# Wait on 2 Javascript function and 2 C# functions?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a webapplication made in ASP.NET Core MVC. I have 2 JavaScript functions and 2 C# functions which should be executed in a row.

What I need to do:

> Click on button > Form pops up > Fill in value > Send value back to method in controller > Use that value in another method in the same controller > Append the value to all rows.

The process I thought about doing:

> There is 1 button > On button click the 2 JavaScript functions are called > First the SetDate function will run, then the AppendDate will run > The SetDate function is combined in a form which is in a partial view > Before it can continue to the AppendDate function it has to finish the first function first (as the form will also call a C# function which gets the result from the form) > Then the other C# function must run by the second 'onclick' event.

The HTML form code below:

```
@model IEnumerable<application.Models.Moederblad>

<div id="element_to_pop_up">
    <a class="b-close">x</a>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Incassodatum", "Moederblads", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "dateForm" }))
    {
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="Incassodatum">Incassodatum</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Bijvoorbeeld: 19-02-2020" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Dat is geen geldige datum" data-val-regex-pattern="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0[1-9]|1[012])[/](19|20)[0-9]{2}$, " id="Incassodatum" name="Incassodatum">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <br>
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" value="Toevoegen" id="submit">
    }
</div>
```

Below the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// DOM Ready
async function SetDate() {
    // Binding a click event
    // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
    $('#AppendDateToIncassoDatum').bind('click', function (e) {

        // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
        e.preventDefault();

        // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

        document.getElementById("dateForm").onsubmit = function () {
            var form = this;
            document.getElementById("IncassoDatum").value = "Laden...";
            setTimeout(function () {
                form.submit();
            }, 3000); // 3 seconds
            return false;
        };
    });
}

//Append functie naar knop
async function AppendDate() {
    await SetDate();
    $('#AppendDateToIncassoDatum').attr('onclick', "location.href='/Moederblads/AppendDateToIncassoDatum'");
}
AppendDate();
});
```

Then the C# method which gets the value from the form (This one is confirmed to be working)

```
    public IActionResult Incassodatum(string Incassodatum)
    {
        string date= "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            date = Incassodatum;
        }
        else
        {
            date = "Daar ging wat mis";
        }
        TempData["Incassodatum"] = $"{Incassodatum}";
        return null; 
    }
```

Then the second C# method which gets the value from the above method and which sets the value for all rows.

```
     [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult AppendDateToIncassoDatum([Bind("<All model properties>")]Moederblad moederblad)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && TempData["Incassodatum"] != null)
        {
            //Datum van vandaag in juiste formaat pakken en in een variabele stoppen
            var datum = TempData["Incassodatum"].ToString();
            if (datum == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            //Model content ophalen
            var model = _context.Moederblad.ToList();

            //We gebruiken hier een foreach statement omdat we elke rij willen updaten
            foreach (var entry in model)
            {
                //Hier check je of de gehele string van Incasso datum niet al een string heeft met de datum van vandaag, zoja breekt hij de operatie af
                //zo niet, gaat ie door en vult hij de datum aan.
                if (entry.Incassodatum.Contains(datum))
                {
                    return View("Error-BA");
                }
                else
                {
                    entry.Incassodatum += ", " + datum;
                }
            }
            //opslaan van de geupdate gegevens
            _context.SaveChanges();

            if (datum != null)
            {
                return View("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        //Mocht het opslaan misgaan, stuur door naar de error page
        else
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

But what happens now is that when I click the button, is that after the form is done loading it directly starts the second Javascript function and the form doesn't even have a value at that point. The second javascript function then runs the C# function and redirects me without a result. It should run whenever the first C# method has the value from the form. Anyone has a idea on how to do this? Stuck for 3 days now.....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right flow. You have confused yourself with using two events over one button.
Let's step through JS flow you have:

1. Once page is loaded then $(document).ready function fires
2. At the end of this function you're calling AppendDate(); explicitly
3. What will AppendDate() function do? It calls first function SetDate() which will bind an onclick hadnler to button with id = AppendDateToIncassoDatum. And then returns run back to AppendDate() which will add an another one handler to the same button with id = AppendDateToIncassoDatum.
4. So when page loaded you'll have a two onclick event over your button. And when you press this button all of these two events will fire one by one: first onr - will show your popup, second - will redirects you to defined location. There will be no pause between this two events.

IMHO, something wrong with a flow you try to impelement. Redirect should be bind to someother control

Comment: Thanks Sergey, will try to think of a new flow.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down your flow:

1. Click on button - built-in client-side functionality
2. Form pops up - JS event handler attached to button's click event manipulates DOM. Just basic JS.
3. Fill in value - User action
4. Send value back to method in controller - AJAX request, still pretty basic
5. Use that value in another method in the same controller - The controller action can call as many other methods or whatever as it needs to. The only thing that matters is the response that's eventually returned in the end.
6. Append the value to all rows. - Just your success callback on the AJAX request. Presumably, you're going to return something like JSON. You'll then use the data in that object to perform some sort of DOM manipulation. Basic JS stuff.

In short, there's entirely nothing complicated here. From where I'm sitting, it's just a basic AJAX request flow, where you request new data from the server and then use JS to dynamically alter the page in someway once you receive the response. What's going on server-side is inconsequential, as long as the ultimate result is returning the required data back to the client.